# USB Stick works on iMac, but on MacBook Pro not

Tags: macbook-pro, imac, usb

i have a strange problem. I formated an usb-Stick (64GB) on my iMac (Mac Journaled Filesystem). Not encrypted, no password. It works fine on several devices (e.g. Popcorn Multimediabox), Windows-Computer (uuugh) and even on the iMac.
But if i plugges it to my Macbook Pro, the USB-Stick is not recognized there. Other Sticks works fine but this stupid single stick not.

This is the last chance for this stick. I'll give it to a poor life by a windows guy if there is no chance to fix it :-(.

Comment: are there any entries in the console when you plug the USB-Stick into the MacPro? If there are, please post them.

Comment: Does it show up in the device tree?

Comment: The usb stick isn't shown in the device tree. Neither in the finder sidebar nor in the system information device tree.

Comment: I'll check the console later this day, when i'm back at home...

Comment: So, the console tells:
10.03.16- KW 10 18:46:02,000 kernel[0]: 000109.320828 PRT6@14400000: AppleUSB30XHCIPort::resetAndCreateDevice: failed to create device after (1) tries, disabling port

Comment: found this: http://osxdaily.com/2015/08/09/mac-usb-ports-not-working-fix/ but in my case it didn't work.

Comment: This is the hardware information from my iMac (yes, i'm from germany):

USB3 Disk:

  Produkt-ID: 0x0732
  Hersteller-ID: 0x05e3  (Genesys Logic, Inc.)
  Version: 0.01
  Seriennummer: 1124600000001636
  Geschwindigkeit: Bis zu 5 Gbit/s
  Hersteller: General 
  Standort-ID: 0x14940000 / 21
  Verfügbare Stromstärke (mA): 1800
  Erforderliche Stromstärke (mA): 224
  Zusätzlicher Betriebsstrom (mA): 396
  Kapazität: 64,02 GB (64.021.856.256 Byte)
  Wechselmedien: Ja
  Absteckbares Laufwerk: Ja
  BSD-Name: disk9
  Partitionstabellentyp: GPT (GUID-Partitionstabelle)

Comment: And here the volumes:
  Volumes:
EFI:
  Kapazität: 209,7 MB (209.715.200 Byte)
  BSD-Name: disk9s1
  Inhalt: EFI
  UUID des Volumes: 0E239BC6-F960-3107-89CF-1C97F78BB46B
Poppstar:
  Kapazität: 63,68 GB (63.677.882.368 Byte)
  Verfügbar: 63,52 GB (63.520.837.632 Byte)
  Beschreibbar: Ja
  Dateisystem: Journaled HFS+
  BSD-Name: disk9s2
  Mount-Point: /Volumes/Poppstar
  Inhalt: Apple_HFS
  UUID des Volumes: ACE8A175-66E6-3E3A-A6B5-07A5C291CD6D

Answer (score 1):

I know the reason ! It works with an USB-Hub with additional power. Plugged into the Macs directly, no stick is working.
On Windows-based machines (even in the Bootcamp on my iMac) the stick is working. It seems, that windows usb-drivers gives more power to usb devices (?)...